# Class 'Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\AbstractController' not found when running unit test for custom module

Tags: magento2, controllers, unit-tests, framework

I tried to make a unit test for my custom module like this:

**app/code/MyCompany/UnitTest/Test/Unit/Controller/SpinTest.php**

```
namespace MyCompany\UnitTest\Controller;

class SpinTest extends \Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\AbstractController
{
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $params = [
          'customer_id' => '3'
        ];
        $this->getRequest()->setPostValue($params);
        $this->dispatch('spin/run');
        $result = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
        $this->assertEquals('200', $result['status']);
    }
}
```

And ran the unit from terminal:

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/MyCompany/UnitTest/Test/Unit/Controller/
```

But i got an error like this:

> Class 'Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\AbstractController' not found in
>   /var/www/mage2/app/code/MyCompany/UnitTest/Test/Unit/Controller/SpinTest.php
>   on line 4

Comment: I think this link helpful to you https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/what-is-unit-testing-in-magento-2/

https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: Have you checked the basic dependency requirement? see above link to verify

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11114

Answer (score -1):

That class does not exist in Magento 2, so you got the error message. The `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` class should be used for every TestCase in Magento 2.x.

So, your code should look like this:

```
namespace MyCompany\UnitTest\Controller;

class SpinTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $params = [
          'customer_id' => '3'
        ];
        $this->getRequest()->setPostValue($params);
        $this->dispatch('spin/run');
        $result = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
        $this->assertEquals('200', $result['status']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like such class exists in Magento - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/TestCase/AbstractController.php